# Is there a regular phonological explanation for the diphthong in the infinitive of the verb "to say" becoming a monophthong in "he says"?

Tags: pronunciation, linguistics

The infinitive form shows a diphthong /seɪ/, while the typical pronunciation of the third-person singular "simple present" form has /ɛ/ as the nucleus /sɛz/. [Wiktionary suggests that the pronunciation /seɪz/ of "he says" is "dialectal".](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/says) Does this occurrence happen with other verbs ending in -/eɪ/ (to my knowledge, "she plays" would be /pleɪz/; "it stays" would be /steɪz/)? If yes, then why did /sɛz/ become the usual form but not /plɛz/? If not, then can we account for the difference in a regular phonological way?

Comment: Esperanto more than English would be the place to ask for intelligent design.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Regularity of phonological sound change and sound correspondences (and providing sound explanations for apparent irregularities) is the bread and butter of historical linguistics. Such regularity underlies natural language systems including English, and are not limited to constructed languages like Esperanto as you erroneously suggest here.

Comment: It's an irregular verb, even though it's spelled like a regular one. The only other verb in English I can think of that behaves similarly is *I do*, *he does*, which also changes the vowel in the 3rd person.

Comment: As Peter says, it's an irregular verb, and it's only one example, so, no, there would appear not to be a regular explanation for it. _Say_ is a very common verb and features in many idioms ("He says, she says"), where it could get reduced easily. Like the situation with _do_, which is already an auxiliary and usually bleached of any sense at all. Once a word gets caught up in the machinery of idiom creation and grammar, it doesn't pay much attention to the rules it used to.

Comment: There is a rule here, but it is backwards from the way you think it is.  The phoneme /e/, which occurs in the 3rd person singular, the past simple form and the past participle form cannot occur in an open syllable in English, but rather must occur with a following consonant. Thus the non-3rd person present form, the plain form, and the present participle cannot use the short vowel /e/ and use the diphthong instead. The same goes for the STRUT vowel in *does/ done* etc.

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=say

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Are you suggesting that the etymological vowel in _to say_ was distinct from the etymological vowel in _to play_, _to stay_, _to sway_ etc.? If yes, then your answer might make sense. If not, then I don't see how your comment explains the difference between _stays_ and _says_. Could you write down phonologically the diachronic development of _say, says, stay, stays_?

Comment: @Araucaria: Alexander Pope (1688–1744) consistently rhymes *says* with *days*, *ways*, and *praise*. So the phoneme of *says* changed from /eɪ/ to /ɛ/. However, the pronunciation of *say* was prevented from changing to /ɛ/ by the fact that it cannot occur in an open syllable.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. You should definitely follow the OED's suggestion that one consult the discussion in E. J. Dobson *Eng. Pronunc.* 1500–1700 (ed. 2, 1968) II. §26. You can find that [here](https://archive.org/details/englishpronuncia0002dobs/page/498/mode/2up?q=26) if you look hard enough. See also *again, wainscot*.

Answer (score 1):

"Say" is an irregular verb, and also very common. As Peter Shor mentioned, "says" used to be pronounced /seɪz/ and is still pronounced that way in a few dialects, however mainly it is pronounced /sɛz/. Perhaps the best explanation is that mentioned by John Lawler, namely that as a result of being included in many idioms and being a very frequent word, the pronunciation has become "naturally compressed", although the written form remains as-is, for the time being at least.

I would add that this seems to be an example of how English pronunciation is evolving. The British Library has an ongoing project to track these too: https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-11640951